# Bind Checkbox Settings to Array Content in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

I have a group of checkboxes in an EmberJS app. I would like to maintain a property in the controller that corresponds to the checked boxes (e.g. contains a string entry with the id of each box that is checked). This property should update itself as boxes are checked or unchecked. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computed property would do

F.e.

```
App.MyController = Em.ObjectController.extend({

  checkboxValues : [Em.Object.create({id:1, check:false}), Em.Object.create({id:2, check:true})],

  checkedIds : function() {
    return this.get('checkboxValues').filterBy('check').mapBy('id').join(',');
  }.property('checkboxValues.@each.check')

});

//template

{{#each checkboxValues}}
  {{id}} {{input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checkedBinding="check"}}
{{/each}}

{{checkedIds}}
```

Comment: Thanks Yuri. I find when I implement this, my template is rendering only one checkbox, corresponding to the last object in the checkboxValues array. Any idea what's up?

Comment: OK I fixed the problem... strange effect of not using parentheses with CoffeeScript when defining the objects. Thanks!